# Confusion about callback function design

Tags: c++, message-queue, listener

I'm designing a library that will be used to intercept and process incoming messages from a message queue. Library users will write their own message handling functions for different kinds of messages received.

I have a `MessageConsumer` class that needs to handle messages of different kinds. I combined all handler functions into an abstract base class called `MessageHandlerBase`. Library users will inherit from this and write their own `MessageHandler` classes.

Relevant parts of the `MessageConsumer` definition:

```
class MessageConsumer {
protected:
    const MessageHandlerBase* m_mesgHandler;        
public:
    MessageConsumer( const std::string& brokerURI, 
                     const std::string& inputQueueName, 
                     const MessageHandlerBase* messageHandler);
    virtual ~MessageConsumer() { this->cleanup(); }
    void runConsumer();

    virtual void onMessage( const Message& message )
    {
         // code to receive and parse messages ...  

        if ( message is of type 1 ) {
            m_mesgHandler->handle_message_type_1(message);
        else if ( message is of type 2 ) {
            m_mesgHandler->handle_message_type_2(message);
         // ... and so on for different types of messages
    }
};
```

And the `MessageHandlerBase` definition is

```
class MessageHandlerBase {
    public:
        virtual void handle_message_type_1( const Message& ) const =0;
        virtual void handle_message_type_2( const Message& ) const =0;
        virtual void handle_cms_exception() const {}
        virtual void handle_transfer_interrupted() const {}
        virtual void handle_transfer_resumed() const {}
};
```

Users usually will just care about handling messages of type 1 & 2 so I just made those pure virtual.

**My big problem is this:** While implementing their own `MessageHandler` class's `handle_message_type_1` and `handle_message_type_2` methods, users need access to methods from one (or possibly more) of their helper classes. How can these classes be made available to `MessageHandler`, without making them global? I can pass the class as a `void*` argument to `handle_message_type_1` but I don't want to because (i) what if I need to pass more than one functions and (ii) then I need to change the call in `MessageConsumer`; I want to totally  abstract these message handling details from `MessageConsumer`.

Is there a more elegant way of handling this whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can these classes be made available to `MessageHandler`, without making them global?

Users need to derive from your class. What stops them putting all kinds of data members into their derivate, referencing whatever they need?

That's the main advantage of using functors instead of function pointers: It makes `void* userData` obsolete.

Comment: Thanks, yes, they'll derive from `MessageHandlerBase` to implement their own handlers. However, teh helper classes are already implemented, so it's undesirable to change that code. For example, there's a class called `Tracker` with a `track()` method that needs to be called when handling messages of type_1. Should they use multiple inheritance, from `MessageHandlerBase` and `Tracker` in this case?

Comment: When they create the derived `MessageHandler` object, users will pass in whatever pointers to helper classes they need to use, and store them within the child class's private data.

Comment: @recipriversexclusion Any class implementing MessageHandlerBase could: a) derive from any other needed classes; b) contain any other needed objects; c) reference other objects via pointers or references. All three options are viable in general. Use whichever (or a combination) that makes the most sense for the design of your program.